# How find $\sum_{k \in A} \frac{1}{k-1} $ for $ A = \{ m^n| \text{ } m, n \in Z \text { and } m, n \ge 2 \} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, analysis, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

If $ A = \{ m^n| \text{  } m, n \in Z  \text {  and  } m, n \ge 2 \} $, then how find $\sum_{k \in A} \frac{1}{k-1} $?

Comment: Might be a good idea to add a quick explanation, e.g., looking for the infinite series $\frac{1}{4-1}+\frac{1}{8-1}+\frac{1}{9-1}+\frac{1}{16-1}+\frac{1}{25-1}+\frac{1}{27-1}+\frac{1}{32-1}+\frac{1}{36-1}+\dots$

Comment: Wolfram says $\sum\limits_{m=2}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{n=m}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m^n-1}$ diverges by the limit test, but it contains many repeating elements, such as $2^6$ and $8^2$, so perhaps it is not the correct way of phrasing your question into Wolfram.

Comment: @barakmanos $n \geq m$ is not required...

Comment: @JohnFernley: Yes, I agree (realized that later). But it still doesn't resolve the "repeating elements" issue.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is 1.

The result is known as Goldbach-Euler theorem.

See [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach-Euler_theorem) for "proof".

For rigorous proof, you could consider sum of reciprocals of all perfect powers, $S$. Note that sum equals
$$
S = \sum_{x \in B}\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{n}} = \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{16}+\ldots+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{27}+\frac{1}{81}+\ldots+\frac{1}{25}+\frac{1}{125}+\ldots
$$
where $B$ is set of all integers not perfect power. Why? All reciprocals of perfect powers are clearly in the sum, and terms in sum are distinct: if
$$
\frac{1}{x^{n}} = \frac{1}{y^{m}}
$$
and $x$ and $y$ are distinct, also $m$ and $n$ are. But since $x$ and $y$ aren't perfect powers, $x^{n}$ and $y^{m}$ are exactly $n$:th and $m$:th powers, respectively, for distinct $m$ and $n$ which is impossible.

But now
$$
S = \sum_{x \in B}\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{n}} = \sum_{x = 2}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{n}}-\sum_{x \in A}\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{n}} \\
= \sum_{x = 2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x(x-1)}-\sum_{x \in A}\frac{1}{x(x-1)} \\
= 1- \sum_{x \in A}\left(\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x}\right) = 1- \sum_{x \in A}\frac{1}{x-1}+\sum_{x \in A}\frac{1}{x} \\
= 1- \sum_{x \in A}\frac{1}{x-1}+S
$$
so
$$
\sum_{x \in A}\frac{1}{x-1} = 1
$$

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer to your question, but if $A$ is a multi-set (where any element may appear more than once), then your series is larger than the sum of all the following series put together:

- $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}=\frac{1}{2-1}-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$
- $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^n}=\frac{1}{3-1}-\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{6}$
- $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^n}=\frac{1}{4-1}-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{12}$
- $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{5^n}=\frac{1}{5-1}-\frac{1}{5}=\frac{1}{20}$
- $\dots$

In other words:

$$\sum\limits_{k\in{A}}\frac{1}{k-1}>\sum\limits_{k\in{A}}\frac{1}{k}=\sum\limits_{m=2}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m^n}=\sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m(m+1)}=1$$

Comment: Not sure whether I should refer to *series* as plural or as singular...

Comment: series is both plural and singular, you've used it fine

Comment: @JohnFernley: So my grammar's OK, then... What about my math please?