# What is the proof that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{P_n -1} =1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Proving that
 $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{P_n -1} =1$$
Where $P_n$ is the nth perfect power.

I think Goldbach has proved this, and I can't even find his proof anywhere. All the results are of the Goldbach conjucture 
and that none of this man's other works is even visible through that. Kind of sad. Also the https://oeis.org/A001597, the oeis on perfect powers has said the same that Goldbach proved it but no reference nor citation to back it up. Any help?

Also is it also possible to find like;
 $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{P_n^2 -1} $$ etc with powers too?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%E2%80%93Euler_theorem

Comment: Thanks for that quick reply you can could have also posted that as an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how find $\sum_{k \in A} \frac{1}{k-1} $ for $ A = \{ m^n| \text{ } m, n \in Z \text { and } m, n \ge 2 \} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/900884/how-find-sum-k-in-a-frac1k-1-for-a-mn-text-m-n-in-z). Although it answers only first part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I will write Goldbach's proof, although not rigorous:

Let $x=1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots.$ Since $\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\cdots=\frac1{2-1},$

$$x-\frac1{2-1}=1+\frac13+\frac15+\frac16+\cdots.$$

Repeat the process for powers of $3$:

$$x-\frac1{2-1}-\frac1{3-1}=1+\frac15+\frac16+\frac17+\cdots.$$

Continuing removing the powers of $5,6,$ etc., until you exhaust the right-hand side to $1$. Eventually, we will obtain:

$$x-\frac1{2-1}-\frac1{3-1}-\frac1{5-1}-\frac1{6-1}-\cdots=1.$$

Notice that $2,3,5,6,10,\dots$ are the non-perfect powers. This means theleft hand side of the equation become $\sum_{n:\text{perfect power}\neq 1}\frac1{n-1}$.

The same technique can be used for $\sum_{n:\text{perfect power}\neq 1}\frac1{n^2-1}.$